# How can you store the precise same time in two different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an oracle database which stores the history of values of some strings. I have the following columns: `ID`, `VALIDFROM`, `VALIDTO`, `VALUE`. Here, `VALIDFROM` and `VALIDTO` are of type TIMESTAMP(6), and `VALUE` is a string. The idea is that `VALIDTO` being null indicates that this is the "latest" version, and that all previous versions are stored along with the time period that they were current.

I have the issue that there is a tiny* difference between `VALIDFROM` and `VALIDTO` of hundredths of seconds. The difference varies, but is always positive and almost always less than a second. The "update" procedure is called from C#, and is as below:

```
PROCEDURE UpdateEntity(p_ID IN OTHERTABLE.ID%TYPE,
                   p_value IN TABLENAME.VALUE%TYPE,
                   p_newParamDate OUT TABLENAME.VALIDFROM%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  p_newParamDate := SYSTIMESTAMP;

  RemoveParams( p_ID, p_newParamDate );
  InsertNewParamValues(p_ID, p_value, p_newParamDate);
END;
```

Then within `RemoveParams` we have:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET VALIDTO = p_newParamDate
WHERE ID = p_ID
AND VALIDTO IS NULL;
```

and within InsertNewParamValues:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
       (ID,   VALIDFROM,      VALIDTO, VALUE  )
VALUES (p_ID, p_newParamDate, NULL,    p_value)
```

Any ideas what could cause this tiny difference in times? Thanks!

Exerpt:

```
VALIDFROM                       VALIDTO
27-OCT-17 12.05.45.028689000 AM 
27-OCT-17 12.05.35.220583000 AM 27-OCT-17 12.05.45.018581000 AM
26-OCT-17 11.35.57.247651000 PM 27-OCT-17 12.05.35.203858000 AM
26-OCT-17 11.35.49.299807000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.35.57.233538000 PM
26-OCT-17 11.34.21.635409000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.35.49.290447000 PM
26-OCT-17 11.32.54.625407000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.34.21.623951000 PM
26-OCT-17 11.32.46.273930000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.32.54.615400000 PM
26-OCT-17 11.04.40.897067000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.32.46.248630000 PM
26-OCT-17 11.04.32.784997000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.04.40.888333000 PM
26-OCT-17 10.59.15.844527000 PM 26-OCT-17 11.04.32.772275000 PM
26-OCT-17 10.59.07.163012000 PM 26-OCT-17 10.59.15.833788000 PM
26-OCT-17 10.35.23.634316000 PM 26-OCT-17 10.59.07.149803000 PM
```

Comment: What are the signatures for `RemoveParams` and `InsertNewParamValues`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I corrected the question, `RemoveParams` does not take the value. They are: `PROCEDURE RemoveParams(p_ID IN OTHERTABLE.EntityID%TYPE,
                       p_newParamDate IN OUT TABLENAME.VALIDFROM%TYPE)` and `PROCEDURE InsertNewParamValues(p_ID IN OTHERTABLE.EntityID%TYPE,
                       p_value IN TABLENAME.VALUE%TYPE,
                       p_newParamDate IN OUT TABLENAME.VALIDFROM%TYPE)`

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Originally it was `p_newParamDate IN`, in both procedures, which had the same problem

Comment: You shouldn't store `VALIDTO` in the table **at all**, you should only store `VALIDFROM`. `VALIDTO` is calculated (trivially) with the `LEAD()` analytic function; if you need it often, you can write a view that includes it (and materialized it if needed for fast execution). What you observed is just one of the many very good reason to avoid duplicating data in your database.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code, in terms of what it's doing. How it's doing it is another story. Since you're assigning the `SYSTIMESTAMP` to a variable and then you use it to update/insert into the same table, Oracle must guarantee that it's kept the same. What I'm thinking is if you have any triggers or check constraints or anything on top of the table definition?

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the comment. I agree it is not the best design, but it is what I have inherited. Perhaps I will try passing in a fixed date from the C# code, as the precise time does not matter (so long as they are the same).

Comment: @g00dy not that I can see. I am genuinely curious as to how it is doing it that could cause this, it is quite bizarre to me. I also tried assigning to a variable and passing that to the other procedures, and I tried combining it all into a single procedure, doing things in different orders, etc. I know very little about database theory but I could not find any mention of a similar issue online when I researched. Beats me!

Comment: @Szmagpie - Yes it might look interesting, but I bet it's some kind of instruction like a trigger that does something in the background. In all cases - it's either a bug in an older version of Oracle that you're using (less likely) or a trigger or another type of procedure that alters that value. Also, since you don't need such a precision, just put a date (may be even with HH24:MI:SS) and you'll be alright. Do Not spend more time on this I urge you :))))